# IndexError: list assignment index out of range in Python

Tags: python, list

I was solving a problem in python by using following code:

```
T = int(raw_input()) 
C=[] 
for x in range(T):     
    C[x]=int(raw_input()) 
res=[] 
for x in range(T):     
    res[x]=2**C[x]+2*C-1      
for x in range(T):     
    print "%d\n",(res[x])
```

and this error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Documents\works\source code\python practice\Test1.py", line 4, in <module>
    C[x]=int(raw_input())
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Can any solve this error pls

Comment: Your list is empty, so e.g. `C[0]` doesn't exist; you can't index beyond the end of a list. Try `C.append(int(raw_input))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your list is empty. perl will expand array automatically but python won't.

```
C.append(int(raw_input()))
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expand a Python list by assigning to an element past the end.

You need to expand the list explicitly but replacing

```
C[x]=int(raw_input())
```

with

```
C.append(int(raw_input()))
```

The same goes for `res`.

Last but not least, the `2*C` in `2**C[x]+2*C-1` will give you a list. It's unclear what you're trying to do here, but `2*C` isn't going to work. Did you mean `2*C[x]`?